# google Mock class seems to not implement

Tags: c++, interface, mocking

I'm new to google mock and I'm trying to mock an interface, but keep getting a linker error with undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Here's my simplified code:

I have the following in a .h file:

```
namespace Mynamespace
{    
    class IMyInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ IMyInterface() {};

        virtual void myFunction() = 0;

    };
}
```

this in another .h file:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <IMyInterface.h>

namespace testing
{
    class MyClassMock : public IMyInterface
    {
    public:
        ~ MyClassMock();
        MyClassMock(int, int, int);

        MOCK_METHOD0(myFunction, void());
    };
}
```

and this in my Test Case .cpp file:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <IMyInterface.h>

namespace testing
{
    TEST(MyClassMock, myFunction)
    {
        MyClassMock mcm(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

cheers,
Simon

EDIT:

Unfortunately the mock still doesn't seem to work. After I added the implementation like this:

```
namespace testing
{
    MyClassMock:: MyClassMock(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }

    MyClassMock::~ MyClassMock()
    {
    }
}
```

"myFunction" will not be called when I do

```
#include "MyClassMock.h"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using namespace testing;

    TEST(MyClassTest, canCallFunction)
    {
        MyClassMock mock(0,0,0);
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, myFunction())
            .Times(AtLeast(1));
    }
```

returning:
EXPECT_CALL(mock, myFunction())
Expected: to be called at least once
Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

Comment: Please include the __full__ error message.

Comment: Your code is missing all includes for the things it uses. Maybe you want to extract a [mcve] first?

Comment: Hey!
thanks for the quick reply!
I added the includes, which were there before, but which I didn't add initially to this post.
I actually worked it out just now by creating a .cpp file with constructor and destructor implementation of the MockClass!

Comment: It's not likely to solve your problem, but you should use `""` rather than `<>` when you `#include` your own headers.  E.g. `#include "IMyInterface.h"` not `#include <IMyInterface.h>.`

Comment: Where is the implementation for `MyClassMock::MyClassMock(int, int, int)` and `MyClassMock::~MyClassMock()` ?

Comment: Hey Sid S,
Yes that was the problem exactly, I didn't add an implementation for MyClassMock. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide implementations for `MyClassMock::MyClassMock(int, int, int)` and `MyClassMock::~MyClassMock()`.

---

On a side not, you should use `""` rather than `<>` when you `#include` your own headers. E.g. `#include "IMyInterface.h"` not `#include <IMyInterface.h>`.  That way, the compiler will search in the current directory prior to the system include path.

Comment: thank you very much
I can create a mock object now, but when running the test it behaves not as expected and doesn't seem to register my function call.
I added the details in my post edit.
Do you know what I'm still doing wrong?
I double checked my version with the google mock cookbook but can't find any deviations which could lead to this behavior

Comment: @SimonSymon, I think you should post that as a new question so that more people will see it.

Comment: Hey, yes will do!